# Chrome DevTools doesn't display my Web-Sql Database in DevTools Resources panel

Tags: google-chrome, web-sql

I declare properly my database in Javascript :

```
self.db = window.openDatabase(DB_CONFIG.name, '1.0', 'My WebSQL test database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Everything is working properly with queries because I get proper results through console.

But When I go to the Resources Devtools panel. The Web SQL field is empty and I can't analyse my database.....

What can I do....?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close and re-open DevTools, after refreshing page.

See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365788